# Load PNG or JPG images into CMFCToolBarImages

Tags: c++, mfc, png

An MFC application creates an array 64*48 size BMP images and a MFC ribbon gallery loads them fine. Since loading the BMPs take time I am trying to create a series of PNG images and then load them into the ribbon gallery.

I tried saving the bitmaps in PNG format by changing the BITMAPINFOHEADER.biCompression property to BI_PNG but no image was saved. I also tried saving the bitmap using CImage object in PNG format:

```
 CImage TempImageObj;
 TempImageObj.Attach(hbmp);
 hr = TempImageObj.Save(filename, Gdiplus::ImageFormatPNG);
```

This time images were saved in files but the CMFCToolBarImages object didn't load them.

Is it possible to create an image in PNG format(other than using CImage Save method) in MFC?
Is it possible to load PNG images into CMFCToolBarImages object?

Answer (score 1):

MFC can't create .png directly. You can use CImage or any free image library like [CxImage](http://www.xdp.it/cximage.htm)

To open back the .png you can use CImage and then use it as HBITMAP object:

```
CImage image;
image.Load( filename );   
HBITMAP hBmp = image; // Warning: image is still the data owner

toolbar.AddImage( hBmp);
```